# No launcher activity found!, yet I've specified one

Tags: java, android

When I specify the .main class as the launcher, it crashes on launch. So I made a new activity called launch that will be used to open the .main class. When I specify .launch as the LAUNCHER, the console tells me that no launcher activity was found.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.homework"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true">

    <activity android:name=".launch"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name=".menu"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

     <activity android:name=".list"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LIST" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: It should be `action.MAIN` and `category.DEFAULT` as in addition to being `category.LAUNCHER`.  You don't need `action.LAUNCH` unless the Activity is an Activity Launcher in itself.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, you may not even need `category.DEFAULT`.  You do need to specify that it's a `MAIN` activity in that it can run solely on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

to

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Ok, so I've changed my intent filter to look exactly like that, and removed the intent filters altogether from the other ones. This is the logcat error that I get:


11-29 10:13:16.053: E/AndroidRuntime(4251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.homework/com.my.homework.launch}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.homework.launch

Comment: And [here's a screenshot of my project](http://i.imgur.com/BcxWI.png) for reference

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been working on this issue for two weeks! you're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Well, does the `com.my.homework.launch` class exist? Does it subclass `Activity`? Also, the action should still be `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`.